# How can i make a LAN with only a PC and an access point to connect a Raspberry Pi without ISP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, wireless-access-point

I know I can use a router/switch to connect both the AP and the PC, but I am
working on a project and I need the least number of devices consuming energy as little as possible.

So I was thinking if I can use an access point connected to the ethernet port in a Windows PC (or Linux if needed) to create a LAN to connect a Raspberry Pi wirelessly and use SSH to control it.

If so, how can I make it?

Comment: Yes you can.   (padding here)

Answer (score 1):

Without a *switch,* nothing changes at all. You only have fewer Ethernet ports (one) but the behavior is identical. You can use the same regular cables (twenty years ago you would have needed a crossover cable but not anymore).

Without a *router,* not much changes either, as devices in the same subnet don't really use a router anyway. (When home routers are involved, LAN traffic only goes through their built-in switch, but not through the router itself.)

The only difference is that without a router, you won't immediately have a DHCP server that provides automatic IP assignment to the Wi-Fi AP's clients. However, there are DHCP servers available for Windows, but you also don't really *need* DHCP if you statically configure the Pi's IP address.

Other than that, though, an AP connected directly to the PC will behave the same as it did before.

(For a simple 1 client setup, you could remove even the access point and use the "hotspot" mode in Windows, which turns the computer's internal Wi-Fi adapter into an access point. For desktops, a PCIe Wi-Fi card could be used. Personally though, I'd avoid Wi-Fi entirely and run Ethernet to the device.)